# Notation to Replace the Input to a Function

Tags: notation

On pg. 54 of a Quantum Computing textbook (Nielsen and Chuang), it's said that:

> it is not surprising that similar techniques can be used to compress the source so that only $H(p, 1 − p)$ qubits are required to store the compressed source, where $H(·)$ is again the Shannon entropy
> function.

I'm confused with the use of the symbol "·" and I wonder what's the name of it as how it's used.

Comment: It's showing the name of the function $H$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thank you for the reply! Howerver, may I ask what does the name of a function mean? Is it the input, ie, what's in the brackets?

Comment: It's a placeholder. Nothing too big to worry about.